# RTDB- How to cleanup .off() of listener .on complex ( listener .on in listener .on('child_add...)

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

Using Firebase Realtime Database
Is there any way to clean up listener .on() that is in listener .on() nested ?

```
useEffect(() => {

    const ChannelRef = database().ref(`/user/${uid}/channel`);
    ChannelRef.keepSynced(true);
    ChannelRef.on('child_added', channel_id => {
          var startTime = ....
          const threadRef = database().ref(`/channel/${channel_id.key}/Thread`).orderByKey().startAt(startTime);
          threadRef.keepSynced(true);
          threadRef.on('value', thread => {.     <--------------------------------   How to cleanup this listenner ?
            dispatch({
               type: 'AddThread',
               payload: thread.val()
            });
    })


    return () => {
          // CleanUp listenner
           ChannelRef.off();
           ChannelRef.keepSynced(false); 
         
          **// How to cleanup database().ref(`/channel/${channel_id.key}/Thread`).orderByKey().startAt(startTime) ?**
   }
  
}, []
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special about managing such listeners. You'll need to keep a list of the listeners you attached, and then call `off` on them when the effect expires.